# appending value to code in java class

Tags: java, dictionary

Might look weird but want to know if this is possible someway in java.
I have an entry(entrya) and I want to set the value to dao setter based on key of entrya, so basically, I want to set a value something like

```
 myDao.set**SomeKeyValue**(entrya.getValue())
```

where SomeKeyValue value should be  `entrya.getKey()`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use **reflection**? [What is reflection and why is it useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

Comment: Are you trying to initialize a POJO object from a Map? If so, you can directly use predefined libraries.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail @Codebender